# Showing that a relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

> Let n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sim_n \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
> $x \sim_n y\Leftrightarrow_{df} x^n - y^n = nx - ny$
> Show that $\sim_n$ is an equivalence relation.

And here is my take on it (I apologize in advance for any notation mistakes, I'm still not quite good at it.):

> Proof Reflexivity:
> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$; to show: $x \sim_n x$
> $\begin{align}x \sim_n x &\Leftrightarrow_{df} x^n - x^n = nx - nx\\ &\Leftrightarrow 0 = 0\end{align} \implies \sim_n$ is reflexive

> Proof Symmetry:
> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$; to show: $x \sim_n y \implies y \sim_n x$
> $\begin{align}x \sim_n y &\Leftrightarrow_{df} x^n - y^n = nx - ny\\ y \sim_n x &\Leftrightarrow -(x^n - y^n) = -nx + ny\end{align} \implies y\nsim x$
> So, the assumption made is wrong, that is, the relation is not symmetric, and therefore not an equivalence relation.

However, I'm unsure whether my proof is valid or not, as the wording of the question, and the following question, that requires ~ to be an equivalence relation, makes me believe it is in fact an equivalence relation.

Comment: You have to show transitivity as well. Moreover, your proof of symmetry is also incomplete.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Well, I didn't show transitivity because it must meet all three requirements, so I thought if it didn't meet one, then the proposition does not stand. And thanks for the heads up, I didn't realize that.

Comment: Follows immediately via the [kernel criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2389827/242) in the linked dupe, with $\,f(x) = x^n-nx\ \ $

Comment: That's not an exact duplicate.  In fact, @Bill, you are presuming the user has covered "the kernal criterion"?  In discrete math??

Comment: @amWhy I see no claim that it is an "exact" dupe.  But it is an abstract dupe. The linked answer contains a full proof and exposition of this criterion. This proof is quite elementary and no more difficult than any direct proof (it essentially just organizes the common structure behind direct proofs of this form). This is what the answer below by A.M. is also hinting at and the OP says he will try doing it that way - so it does not seem beyond their reach.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a general fact you can show:

Let $f : A \to B$ be a function and define $\sim_f$ on $A$ by $$x \sim_f y \Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y).$$

I encourage you to prove this is always an equivalence relation on your own and let me know if you face any issues with this.

---

Once you have done that, note that in your question, the relation is defined by $$x \sim_n y \Leftrightarrow x^n - y^n = nx - ny.$$
Note that the last equation can be rewritten as $$x^n - nx = y^n - ny.$$
Thus, defining $f_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $f_n(x) = x^n - nx$ and using the earlier result finishes the job.

Comment: That seems an interesting way to solve it, I'll try working on it using that way. Thank you for the lead.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: The fact mentioned here can also be found in some older posts on [math.se], such as: [Prove that the relation on $X$ given by $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236777).

Comment: @Martin It's the same as the [kernel criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389834/242) that I linked to earlier in the proposed dupe (in a comment in the answer).