# Equivalence relation: $x \sim y \iff [x]_1 = [y]_1$

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ be the floor function and $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$. **Claim:** The following is an equivalence relation:

> Let $R \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$: $$xRy \iff [x]_1 = [y]_1$$
> where $$\begin{align*} [x]_k = \text{k-th digit of } x = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\#x -k}} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\#x -k +1}} \right \rfloor \end{align*}$$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \le \#x$ (reading digits from left to right, e.g., $[1245]_3 = 4$), and $$\#x = \text{number of digits of }x = \lfloor \log_{10}(x) \rfloor + 1$$.

**Proof:**

- Reflexivity: $xRx \iff [x]_1 = [x]_1$, which is true for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$.
- Symmetry:

$$\begin{split}
xRy &\iff [x]_1 = [y]_1\\
&\iff \left \lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\#x-1}} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\#x}} \right \rfloor  = \left \lfloor \frac{y}{10^{\#y-1}} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{y}{10^{\#y}} \right \rfloor\\
&\iff \left \lfloor \frac{y}{10^{\#y-1}} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{y}{10^{\#y}} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\#x-1}} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\#x}} \right \rfloor\\
&\iff [y]_1 = [x]_1\\
&\iff yRx
\end{split}$$

- Transitivity: If $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $[x]_1  = [y]_1$ and $[y]_1 = [z]_1 \Longrightarrow [x]_1 = [y]_1 = [z]_1 \Longrightarrow [x]_1=[z]_1$. Hence, $xRz$.

**Q.E.D.**

### Question:

Is this proof correct? For me, it looks legit.

Comment: If $g:A \to B$ is any function at all, then the relation $R$ on $A$ defined by $xRy \leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation, by an argument similar to yours but just generalized.

Comment: Yes. More generally, [a relation given by x∼y if f(x)=f(y) is an equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236777/prove-that-the-relation-on-x-given-by-x-sim-y-if-fx-fy-is-an-equivalen).

Comment: $[x]_1 = [y]_1 \iff [y]_1 = [x]_1$ so you can skip the two lines in the middle. After simplilfying  that you should be able to realize that the three properties can be proved without using the definition of $[x]_k$

Comment: Also, after the comments of coffeemath and Anne Bauval, a nice exercise: show that every equivalence relation $R$ on any set $A$ is of the form $xRy \iff f(x) = f(y)$ for some adequate $B$ and $f:A \to B$.