# Questions of bijection for $h: \mathbb{N}/R \to \mathbb{F}_9$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Let $R \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$: $$xRy \iff g_1(x) = g_1(y)$$
where $g_1(x) = \left \lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(x) \rfloor}} \right \rfloor$

Let $h: \mathbb{N}/R \to \mathbb{F}_9 \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+1) $ such that
$$[1]_R \mapsto (x^2+1)\\
[2]_R \mapsto 1+(x^2+1)\\
[3]_R \mapsto 2+(x^2+1)\\
[4]_R \mapsto x+(x^2+1)\\
[5]_R \mapsto x+1+(x^2+1)\\
[6]_R \mapsto x+2+(x^2+1)\\
[7]_R \mapsto 2x+(x^2+1)\\
[8]_R \mapsto 2x+1+(x^2+1)\\
[9]_R \mapsto 2x+2+(x^2+1)$$
where $\mathbb{F}_9$ is the finite field of order $9$, and $\mathbb{N}/R$ as the quotient set w.r.t the [equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516390/equivalence-relation-x-sim-y-iff-x-1-y-1) on the set $\mathbb{N}$.

**Questions:**

1. Can $h$ be shortened using an explicit formula?
2. What is the explicit inverse of $h$?

**Attempt:**
I tried to solve these questions, but is too difficult for me. Any hints will help.

## EDIT

I changed the bijection in order to make it simpler. In this way, I found a shorthand way to have this bijection:

Let $I = (x^2+1)$ be the (two-sided) ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ generated by $m(x) = x^2+1$. The inverse of $h$ is the following: Take the map $h^{-1}: \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/I \to \mathbb{N}/R$ such that $$h^{-1}(f(x)+I)=[g(3)+1 \pmod{10}]_R$$ where $f(x) - g(x) \in I$ and $g(x) \in \{0, 1, 2, x, x+1, x+2, 2x, 2x+1, 2x+2\}$.

Comment: Your question uses $g_1$ and in that case the formula simplifies to $$g_1(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor}}\right\rfloor$$, so you could avoid posting the general formula.

Comment: I am actually gonna use this comment for simplicity

Comment: Also, the expressions defining $h$ can be simplified and you should do it. For example $h([6]) = x^2 = -1 = 2$.

Comment: @jjagmath, I changed the elements for $\mathbb{F}_9$. I noticed that the elements were incorrect. Thank You!